# R Shiny SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, r, shiny

I would like to query an ODBC database within Shiny. All I need is for the user to be able to type in someone's ID number, for example, and then to print out the entire row in the table, which is located in the database. What I have so far allows for inputs, but does not seem to be querying the database and printing that information.

This is what I have:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)
library(sqldf)

#connect to database
dbhandle = odbcDriverConnect(...)


library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(

 pageWithSidebar(

   headerPanel("Hide Side Bar example"),
   sidebarPanel(
     textInput("Id", "Enter Account Number below"),
     submitButton(text="Submit")
   ),
   mainPanel(
   tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
    )
  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  myData <- reactive({

  #build query
  query = paste0("SELECT Fullname FROM Table WHERE ID= ", input$Id)

  #store results
  res <- sqlQuery(conn = dbhandle, query = query) 

  #close database
  databaseClose(dbhandle)

  #return results
  res
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you need to `fetch()` the `res` you requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a handful of changes you'll need to make before this works.  Some of the key concepts that need to be pointed out:

1. You have no `output$tbTable` object.  This means that your `myData` reactive is never being called, so you're never querying your database.
2. You are using an `RODBC` database connection, and then using `DBI` style arguments in `sqlQuery`.  You should use either `DBI` (via `RSQLServer`, perhaps--I've never used it) or `RODBC` (I use this a lot).
3. You are closing `dbhandle` after the first time you call it.  Is this the intended behavior? That the user should only get one chance at hitting the database?

Some minor notes:

1. I recommend using `RODBCext` so that you can use parameterized queries.
2. `Table` is a reserved word in SQL.  I'm not sure if this is a placeholder or not, but it can be helpful to wrap your table components in brackets, such as [schema].[table_name].[column_name]
3. You didn't direct the query to a schema.  This may or may not present an issue.  Since your query was never called, you didn't have a chance to see if it threw an error.

My recommendation for your code would be:

```
library(RODBCext) # Also loads RODBC
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Hide Side Bar example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("Id", "Enter Account Number below"),
      submitButton(text="Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {      
  myData <- reactive({
    req(input$Id)

    #connect to database 
    dbhandle = odbcDriverConnect(...)

    #build query
    query = "SELECT [Fullname] FROM [schema].[table_name] WHERE [ID] = ?"

    #store results
    res <- sqlExecute(channel = dbhandle, 
                      query = query,
                      data = list(input$Id),
                      fetch = TRUE,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

    #close the connection
    odbcClose(dbhandle)
    #return results
    res
  })

  output$tbTable <- 
    renderTable(
      myData()
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I seem to recall there is a way to close the database connection when the session closes, but I can't get it to work the way I expected with `session$onSessionEnded(odbcClose(dbhandle))`, so someone else may be able to fill in the gap there.

If you don't want to create a new connection everytime you click the button, you can create the connection outside of the reactive, and just not close it.  This will leave a hanging connection, though, which I'm not fond of doing.

Comment: Beautiful, excellent suggestions! It worked, and I greatly appreciate your help. This was exactly the issue, and now I know how to make this work for future projects!

Comment: As a follow up, if I wanted to query with OR, how would I note that in the sqlExecute? Say I want the query to be "SELECT [Fullname] FROM [schema].[table_name] WHERE [ID] = ? OR [Lastname] = ?"                          How would I put that in the 'data' argument of sqlExecute? I have tried 'list(input$Id, input$Name' and it doesn't seem to do the job. Essentially, I am building a search box where someone could query my database by ID or Name. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Adding the list element as you've done is what I would have tried.  To ask an obvious question, have you defined the `input$Name` control yet?  If not, that would explain the failure.  The list in `data` is converted to a data frame object before parameterizing the query.  If there's `NULL` element, it won't create a column, and won't get passed into the query.

Comment: I defined input$Name as a textInput, identical to input$Id. I have two text input fields, and a submit button. I noticed that searching by ID still works fine, but searching by Name only works if something is in the ID input box. In other words, if I just search someone's name and hit 'submit', nothing will happen, but if I put anything in the ID input box, the search by name works. In fact, the query does not even go through if I don't have anything in the ID box. I know this because if I do a blank search in ID, I get my column names and no data in the output, but otherwise I don't.

Comment: Benjamin, I appreciate your help so far greatly. Would you possibly know how to fix the issue I described in my last comment? It would be extremely helpful. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an immediately obvious solution.  This is really a SQL problem, in that you are having to maintain a query that can accommodate the possibility of a null input from shiny.  This requires knowing what the shiny control returns if no input is given, and passing the appropriate value to the SQL query.  In some ways, it may be easier to use a series of conditionals to construct the query based on the inputs. ie `paste0("SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE ", if (!is.null(input$Id)) "ID = ?" else "", ...)`

Comment: Great, thank you very much. That just might work, I will give it a try.

Comment: I was wondering if you wanted to create two reactive r shiny tables using two queries with the odbc connection for a single application. Is that possible?

Comment: @Gabriella sure. You would create your connection object so that it is accessible to both reactives and don't close it until the end of the shiny session.

Comment: Would you happen to be able to help me over here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77909071/r-shiny-create-multiple-reactive-tables-from-multiple-sql-queries-to-display-in

Answer (score 0):

A `reactive` is a function : as long as you don't call it, it's not evaluated.

To fill in the table with the result of the query, you just have to add this code to your server function after the closing parenthesis of the `reactive` :

```
output$tbTable<- renderTable(mydata())
```

Comment: Thank you as well, this was exactly my issue.