# Use Shiny App to Query a SQL Server DB

Tags: r

I guess I really don't understand this process like I thought I did.  I found the link below, and it seems pretty helpful, but after making only slight modifications, I can't get it to do what I want.

[R Shiny SQL Server Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120389/r-shiny-sql-server-query)

I just want to launch a webpage and have a user enter a parameter, to be passed into a query.

```
library(RODBCext)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Hide Side Bar example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("CATEGORY", "Enter CATEGORY below"),
      submitButton(text="Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
      )

    )
  )
)

browser()

server <- function(input, output, session)      
  myData <- reactive({
    req(input$Id)

    #connect to database 
    dbhandle = odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=my_server;database=data_WH;trusted_connection=true')

    browser()

    #build query
    #query = "SELECT * FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] where [CATEGORY] = '1070'"
query = "SELECT * FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] where [CATEGORY] = ?"

    browser()

    #store results
    res <- sqlExecute(channel = dbhandle, 
                      query = query,
                      data = list(input$Id),
                      fetch = TRUE,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

    #close the connection
    odbcClose(dbhandle)
    #return results
    res
  })

  output$tbTable <- 
    renderTable(
      myData()
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The SQL string is fine.  I entered browser, to try to debug the script, as described in the link below.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html

browser()

It didn't pause the code; it didn't help me debug the code.  It didn't do anything at all.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Change input$Id to input$CATEGORY as a first step

Comment: Well, that was a great catch awchisholm!  I made the change you recommended but it didn't fix the problem.  I still can't enter the ID and see the results in my browser window.  I don't see anything at all when I enter a valid ID and click the button.  I though that's what the script does.  Unless I am totally misunderstanding the code.  No matter what, I definitely need to boost my Shiny IQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your server function is incorrectly defined.

A function defined of the form

```
fn <- function(arg1, arg2)
 expression1

 expression2
```

Is actually going to be evaluated as

```
fn <- function(arg1, arg2){
  expression1
}

expression2
```

In your `server` function, because you didn't place your braces, the only expression in the function definition is creating the `myData` reactive.  Your `output$tbTable` element is completely separate from your function, never gets called in the app, and so your reactive is never processed.  You should try this:

```
library(RODBCext)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Hide Side Bar example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("CATEGORY", "Enter CATEGORY below"),
      submitButton(text="Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
      )

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)    
{ # NOTE THE BRACE HERE
  myData <- reactive({
    req(input$CATEGORY)

    #connect to database 
    dbhandle = odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=my_server;database=data_WH;trusted_connection=true')

    #build query
    #query = "SELECT * FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] where [CATEGORY] = '1070'"
    query = "SELECT * FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] where [CATEGORY] = ?"

    #store results
    res <- sqlExecute(channel = dbhandle, 
                      query = query,
                      data = list(input$CATEGORY),
                      fetch = TRUE,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

    #close the connection
    odbcClose(dbhandle)
    #return results
    res
  })

  output$tbTable <- 
    renderTable(
      myData()
    )

} # AND NOTE THE CLOSING BRACE HERE

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: VERY COOL!!  Thanks so much Benjamin!!

Comment: Hi ryguy72, did this work you?? I am Struggling to get this right. I am getting an error which says  Error: odbcValidChannel(channel) is not TRUE